# How to do action based on status code in ssh?

Tags: python, ssh

I want to do some action based on the status code from one of the commands in ssh.

For example, I have the below ssh command.

```
python $BASEDIR/Demo.py --message hello --environment test
```

So, now the above Demo.py gives status code 1 and 0.

So, if the status code is 1 then I want to execute some other command if it is 0 then I want to exit from ssh.

How can I do the same?

Comment: you can easily send commands like that to be run via ssh if the remote server has the script `Demo.py`, otherwise it's more troublesome

Comment: How to do if the remote server has script?